# How to block Google Images while allowing Google on Windows 10 PC?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I am trying to block Google images while allowing google.com. I am on a Windows 10 PC. I use google chrome. Is there anyway I can do this? Thank you.

Comment: What is your end goal here? Are you just wanting to make sure there are no pornographic images? I can’t think of any reason to block all image search functionality. So please explain.

Comment: No I am just trying to block the place where it shows Google Images. I am sorry for not clarifying. I am not trying to block all images. I am trying to block the images.google.com domain while allowing Google.

Comment: If it is that specific you can simply place an entry in your HOSTS file for that domain and send it to 127.0.0.1. `127.0.0.1 images.google.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the images under `Settings > Site Settings > Content > Images`.

Or type `chrome://settings/content/images` into the address bar.

Comment: This isn't really effective since it disables some features of a website that are important. I am just trying to block the Google Images section under the search bar. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [building a small Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) that automatically detects if the browser is using Google Images (something like [this](https://github.com/micahlt/latinifier/blob/9bd11930d34ad99e153a1efe6812b02f918a7368/src/manifest.json#L17)) and then [delete the image elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) with Javascript.  Then again, it depends on how far you want to go and your technical experience level.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the tool "Hide Google Search Favicons":

https://www.extfans.com/accessibility/minacgnadopeelfnhjhlmoobniogpded/